# Equal height width columns CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Since we have solved one of the issues, now I have another one. How to create all columns to be equal in height and width even the text on some of them is more? I have tried with flexbox, but no luck at all. Every suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[Width example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AJ3r.jpg)

[Height example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvhLt.jpg)

Here is the code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .containers {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .container {
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .price {
      list-style-type: none;
      border: 1px solid #eee;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .price:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .price .header {
      background-color: #6f8bab20;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    .price li {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .price .grey {
      background-color: #eee;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .button {
      background-color: #253c57;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 25px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    #price {
      font-size: 50px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .columns {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .button {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 style="text-align: center">Responsive Pricing Tables</h2>
  <p style="text-align: center">
  </p>
  <div class="containers">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
        <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
        <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
        <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
        <li>Home/gym based</li>
        <li>Video Demonstration</li>
        <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
        <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header" style="background-color: #65e6f7">
          Vip Online Coaching
        </li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 120 / month</li>
        <li>Fully tailored macronutrient/nutritional guide</li>
        <li>Fully tailored training programme</li>
        <li>Exercise technique analysis</li>
        <li>Supplement guidance</li>
        <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
        <li>Weekly check-ins</li>

        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header">Nutrition Coaching</li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
        <li>Adapted to your goals, personal preferences and allergies</li>
        <li>Fully tailored nutritional plan</li>
        <li>Shopping guidance</li>
        <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
        <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header">3 Months Online Coaching</li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 300 / month</li>
        <li>Fully tailored macronutrient/nutritional guidance</li>
        <li>Fully tailored training programme</li>
        <li>Supplement guidance</li>
        <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
        <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="price">
        <li class="header">Video Consultation</li>
        <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 40 / month</li>
        <li>Overcoming healthy lifestyle barriers</li>
        <li>Psychonutritional barriers</li>
        <li>Training questions</li>
        <li class="grey">
          <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A CONSULTATION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please update your code to be a minimal, reproducible snippet instead. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service where we just fix your code....

Comment: Hi, @Lissy93 I completely agree with you and I apologize. I do not post my code here with the intent someone to edit my code and me just copy and paste it. If possible, would you explain, how to make the snippet minimal?  

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.containers{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container{
  padding: 10px;
}

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  height: 100%;
}

.price:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.price .header {
  background-color: #6f8bab20;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 25px;
}

.price li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #253c57;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#price {
  font-size: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
      width: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
      width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .columns {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .button{
      font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
  <h2 style="text-align: center">Responsive Pricing Tables</h2>
  <p style="text-align: center">
  </p>
  <div class="containers">
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="price">
              <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
              <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
              <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals aaaaaaaaaaaaaajdfh mbjhzdgc</li>
              <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
              <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
              <li>Home/gym based</li>
              <li>Video Demonstration</li>
              <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
              <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
              <li class="grey">
                <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="price">
              <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
              <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
              <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
              <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
              <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
              <li>Home/gym based</li>
              <li>Video Demonstration</li>
              <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
              <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
              <li class="grey">
                <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="price">
              <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
              <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
              <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
              <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
              <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
              <li>Home/gym based</li>
              <li>Video Demonstration</li>
              <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
              <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
              <li class="grey">
                <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="price">
              <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
              <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
              <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
              <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
              <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
              <li>Home/gym based</li>
              <li>Video Demonstration</li>
              <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
              <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
              <li class="grey">
                <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="price">
              <li class="header">Training Coaching</li>
              <li class="grey" id="price">&pound 60 / month</li>
              <li>Fully tailored training programme adapted to your goals</li>
              <li>Technical review of the exercises</li>
              <li>Bodyweight/gym equipment</li>
              <li>Home/gym based</li>
              <li>Video Demonstration</li>
              <li>Weekly check-ins</li>
              <li>24/7 WhatsApp contact</li>
              <li class="grey">
                <a href="#" class="button">BOOK A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```